# Strip HTML and Shortcodes from wordpress that uses Fusion Builder

Tags: php, wordpress

First thing is i'm using Wordpress > Avada Theme > and Fusion Core Plugin.

What i want to do is strip the content of any post down to a few characters. And what i have works with almost everything minus, post content that uses the Fusion Core plugin.

Here is my function that should get the excerpt and shrink it down.

```
function get_my_excerpt_by_id($post_id, $length, $strip_html)
{   
    if(!$length)        
      $excerpt_length = 35;     
    else        
      $excerpt_length = $length;

    if(!isset($strip_html) || $strip_html == true)      
      $strip_html = true;

    $the_post = get_post($post_id); //Gets post ID
    $the_excerpt = apply_filters('the_content',$the_post->post_content); //Gets post_content to be used as a basis for the excerpt

    if($strip_html == true)
        $the_excerpt = strip_tags(strip_shortcodes($the_excerpt)); //Strips tags and images

    $words = explode(' ', $the_excerpt, $excerpt_length + 1);

    if(count($words) > $excerpt_length) :
        array_pop($words);
        array_push($words, '…');
        $the_excerpt = implode(' ', $words);
    endif;

    return $the_excerpt; 
}
```

So this works like a charm EXCEPT if i'm using Fusion Core Plugin for one of the post types beccause then i get this

'.fusion-fullwidth-4 { padding-left: 0px !important; …'

Any idea why its not stripping the shortcodes and css and html? Although in looking at it, maybe its just the css? that is staying. Thank you!

EDIT::
SO it turns out that its just the css that stays. So now i have to figure out how to remove them. Everything after a period....

Answer (score 2):

I just wanted to post my answer here in case anybody need it for later, Thank you Ghulam Ali, for the help with this answer.

So it turns out that when using Fusion Core, it adds `<style>` tags, that when removed using strip_tags, would leave the css code nested inside of the  tag.

So, to fix this we first remove all tags, MINUS `<style>` using

`$the_excerpt = strip_tags(strip_shortcodes($the_excerpt), '<style>');`

THEN, we strip out the `<style>` tags and its content using this nifty regex. (that i did not write but don't know how to give the right credit to the person that did).

`$the_excerpt = preg_replace("|<style\b[^>]*>(.*?)</style>|s", "", $the_excerpt);`

This is the full function i use to get the content and output an excerpt from it. I hope this comes in handy for somebody!

```
function get_my_excerpt_by_id($post_id, $length, $strip_html){
    if(!$length)
        $excerpt_length = 35;
    else
        $excerpt_length = $length;

    if(!isset($strip_html) || $strip_html == true)
        $strip_html = true;

    $the_post = get_post($post_id); //Gets post ID
    $the_excerpt = apply_filters('the_content',$the_post->post_content);//$the_post->post_content); //Gets post_content to be used as a basis for the excerpt

    if($strip_html == true)
    {
        $the_excerpt = strip_tags(strip_shortcodes($the_excerpt), '<style>');
        $the_excerpt = preg_replace("|<style\b[^>]*>(.*?)</style>|s", "", $the_excerpt);
    }

    $words = explode(' ', $the_excerpt, $excerpt_length + 1);

    if(count($words) > $excerpt_length) :
        array_pop($words);
        array_push($words, '…');
        $the_excerpt = implode(' ', $words);
    endif;

    return $the_excerpt;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

add style tag into strip tags

```
$the_excerpt = strip_tags(strip_shortcodes($the_excerpt), '<style>'); //add tags like
```

i hope this will fix.

Comment: That's actually now how strip_tags works. The tags above are allowable tags so those would be skipped. But thank you for taking the time to try to help me.

Comment: do you want to remove shortcode from the content. have you tried preg_replace function?

Comment: When changing to  get_the_content, i'm returning no content at all. What is the difference there?

Comment: I have no tried preg_replace, looking that up now. but i really just want to remove css. The shortcodes seem to be removed.

Comment: the_content will return with echo while get_the_content will not return echo. I have same function used before that will strip all the tags, shortcode,

Comment: Its just not removing the css, i keep just getting this `.fusion-fullwidth-3 { padding-left: 0px !important; padding-right: 0px !important; }`

Comment: I'm guessing yes. Fusion Core Plugin gives you a wysiwyg approach to coding certain posts and pages. This puts shortcodes everywhere. I thought removing the shortcodes would fix this, but for some odd reason everything minus the css that is added via the shortcode is still appearing. Does this make sense?

Comment: check my edit. simple add the style tag into strip tag function.

Comment: for more if you want css remain copy all css and add it into style.css. and my pleasure any time

Answer (score 0):

I'd also like to post my solution - since fusion ads shortcodes. None of the previous solutions mentioned here worked. This was the solution I used (within the loop), found it here [(remove fusion builder shortcodes)](https://gist.github.com/bpmore/85f5a32096218382fbb946d1f1166fb5)

```
$content = preg_replace('/\[\/?fusion.*?\]/', '', get_the_content());
```